# ArrayList returning wrong results

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm using an ArrayList to store player names in my adnroid app. I call the names using their index in the list and use them to update a text view. However, this doesn't always work, even though the index is correct sometimes it pull up the wrong list entry.

I don't know what to try to fix it as I can't figure out why it's happening.

PlayerNames.java

```
   playerArray = new ArrayList<>();

    saveName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = enterName.getText().toString();
            playerArray.add(name);
            setPlayerNames();

        }
    });
```

QuizQuestions.java

```
    private ArrayList playerList = null;
private int z;
public class getQuestion extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> { 
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);


        try{
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Bundle impExtras = intent.getExtras();
            z = (int) impExtras.get("NEXT");
        } catch(Exception e){
            z = 0;
        }


        playerList = PlayerNames.getPlayerArray();

        if (z < (playerList.size() - 1) && playerList.size() != 0){
            Log.i("index z: ", String.valueOf(z));
            Log.i("list entry at index z: ", playerList.get(z).toString());
            currPlayer.setText(playerList.get(z).toString());
            Log.i("playerName: ", currPlayer.getText().toString());
            z++;


        } else if (z==(playerList.size() - 1) && playerList.size() != 0){
            Log.i("index z: ", String.valueOf(z));
            Log.i("list entry at index z: ", playerList.get(z).toString());
            currPlayer.setText(playerList.get(z).toString());
            Log.i("playerName: ", currPlayer.getText().toString());
            z=0;

        } else{
            currPlayer.setText("Anon");
        }


        playerNow = currPlayer.toString();

        Bundle extras = new Bundle();

        extras.putInt("NEXT", z);



    }
```

CorrectAnswer.java

```
     private String currPlayer;
private ArrayList playerList = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    playerList = PlayerNames.getPlayerArray();
    Collections.shuffle(playerList,new Random(System.nanoTime()));

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    currPlayer = (String) extras.get("PLAYER");

    if (playerList.size() > 0) {
        player = playerList.get(0).toString();
        if (player.equals(currPlayer)) {
            player = playerList.get(1).toString();
        }
    } else {
        player = "Anonymous";
    }


    giveDrinks.setText("Give " + player + " " + (i) + " drinks");
    giveDrinks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent nextQuest = new Intent(CorrectAnswer.this, QuizQuestions.class);
            nextQuest.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(nextQuest);
            finish();
        }
    });

    challenge.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent newChallenge = new Intent(CorrectAnswer.this, Challenge.class);
            newChallenge.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(newChallenge);
            finish();
        }
    });



}
```

My Logcat

```
I/index z:: 0    
I/list entry at index z:: player name at index 0    
I/playerName:: player name at index 0    
I/index z:: 1    
I/list entry at index z:: player name at index 1    
I/playerName:: player name at index 1    
I/index z:: 2    
I/list entry at index z:: player name at index 2    
I/playerName:: player name at index 2    
I/index z:: 0    
I/list entry at index z:: player name at index 2    
I/playerName:: player name at index 2     
I/index z:: 1    
I/list entry at index z:: player name at index 0    
I/playerName:: player name at index 0
```

I really don't understand it.

Comment: Where is currPlayer used? and when the second code is called?

Comment: Edited to show that :)

Comment: Can you please try to create a [mcve]? Your code shows some related snippet, but that isn't enough to understand the program flow.

Comment: I think still something is missing.. Where do you use z? Is plyaersList being mutated or used somewhere else?

Comment: the playerArray is being retrieved in another activity, seperate from the activity that it is originally stored in and there it is used to fill another, private ArrayList that then get's shuffled, would that shuffle the original?

Comment: Solved, the shuffle functions were shuffling the original ArrayList. Thanks for the help anyway guys.

Comment: Yeah it was a mutation somewhere else, probably the shuffling.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList must have been mutated somewhere else in the code, making the items inside changing positions before being extracted in `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score 1):

## Unmodifiable list

If you want your `List` to never change its elements, make it unmodifiable. Then, if you have code somewhere along the line of execution that attempts to add, delete, or replace an element, an exception will be thrown.

In recent versions of Java, use the new `List.of` methods.

In older Java, use the `Collections` utility class. Pass your list to the `static` class method [`unmodifiableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)). You get back a `List` implementation that relies on the original list. So if you expect to separately modify the original, and don’t want those changes seen by users of the unmodifiable list, feed a copy of the original to `unmodifiable`.